# Understand numpy's transpose

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following python code

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as it

ref_list = [0, 1, 2]
p = it.permutations(ref_list)
transpose_list = tuple(p)

#print('transpose_list', transpose_list)

na = nb = nc = 2


A = np.zeros((na,nb,nc))
n = 1
for la in range(na):
    for lb in range(nb):
        for lc in range(nc):
            A[la,lb,lc] = n
            n = n + 1   


factor_list = [(i+1)*0.0 for i in range(6)]
factor_list[0] = 0.1
factor_list[1] = 0.2
factor_list[2] = 0.3
factor_list[3] = 0.4





sum_A = np.zeros((na,nb,nc))
for m, t in enumerate(transpose_list):
    if abs(factor_list[m]) < 1.e-3:
        continue 
    factor_list[m]  * np.transpose(A, transpose_list[m]) 

    print('inter', m, t, factor_list[m], np.transpose(A, transpose_list[m])[0,0,1] )

B = np.transpose(A, (0, 2, 1))
C = np.transpose(A, (1, 2, 0))

for la in range(na):
    for lb in range(nb):
        for lc in range(nc):
            print(la,lb,lc,'A',A[la,lb,lc],'B',B[la,lb,lc],'C',C[la,lb,lc])
```

The result is

```
inter 0 (0, 1, 2) 0.1 2.0
inter 1 (0, 2, 1) 0.2 3.0
inter 2 (1, 0, 2) 0.3 2.0
inter 3 (1, 2, 0) 0.4 5.0
0 0 0 A 1.0 B 1.0 C 1.0
0 0 1 A 2.0 B 3.0 C 5.0
0 1 0 A 3.0 B 2.0 C 2.0
0 1 1 A 4.0 B 4.0 C 6.0
1 0 0 A 5.0 B 5.0 C 3.0
1 0 1 A 6.0 B 7.0 C 7.0
1 1 0 A 7.0 B 6.0 C 4.0
1 1 1 A 8.0 B 8.0 C 8.0
```

My question is, why the `inter 1`  and `inter 3` get 3.0 and 5.0?  The objective is to obtain
`P(A)[0,0,1]`.

For `inter 1`, it is `(0, 2, 1)`, I thought about `(0,2,1)` on `[0,0,1] -> [0,1,0]`

For `inter 3`, it is `(1, 2, 0)`, I thought about `(1,2,0)` on `[0,0,1] -> [0,1,0]`

So the value should be the same. The output are not the same (`3.0` and `5.0`). So apparently I misunderstood `np.transpose`. What would be the correct understanding that what happened inside `np.transpose`?

More specifically, from [How does numpy.transpose work for this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100702/how-does-numpy-transpose-work-for-this-example), Anand S Kumar's answer
I tried to think from both `(0, 2, 1)` and `(1, 2, 0)`, both lead to

```
(0,0,0) -> (0,0,0)
(0,0,1) -> (0,1,0)
```

I guess it related to the inverse of permutation. But I am not sure why.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny For the line `sum_A = np.zeros((na,nb,nc,nd))`, if I modify into 2 dimensions with different size, e.g., `na=2` and `nb=1`, it will lead to inconsistent dimensions in the summed array

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does numpy.transpose work for this example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33100702/how-does-numpy-transpose-work-for-this-example)

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I tried 2*3 case,`inter 0 (0, 1) 0.1 2.0
inter 1 (1, 0) 0.2 4.0`;  `(0,1)` is the original one, `(1,0)` lead to the other. There is no inconsistency. I guess it came from inverse of permutation, if I want `P^-1[A] != P[A]`, it leads to at least 3 dimension. But 3 and 4 are not that different

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I read the link. I don't think it answers my question. I edited my question using simplified example and refereed to the link

Comment: `B` switches the last 2 dimensions.  So `B[0,0,1] == A[0,1,0] == 3`.  More generally , `print(la,lb,lc,'A',A[la,lb,lc],'B',B[la,lc,lb],'C',C[lc,lb,la])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more direct way of making your `A`:

```
In [29]: A = np.arange(1,9).reshape(2,2,2)
In [30]: A
Out[30]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[5, 6],
        [7, 8]]])
```

The transposes:

```
In [31]: B = np.transpose(A, (0, 2, 1))
    ...: C = np.transpose(A, (1, 2, 0))
In [32]: B
Out[32]: 
array([[[1, 3],
        [2, 4]],

       [[5, 7],
        [6, 8]]])
In [33]: C
Out[33]: 
array([[[1, 5],
        [2, 6]],

       [[3, 7],
        [4, 8]]])
```

two of the cases:

```
In [35]: A[0,0,1], B[0,1,0],C[0,1,0]
Out[35]: (2, 2, 2)
In [36]: A[1,0,0], B[1,0,0], C[0,0,1]
Out[36]: (5, 5, 5)
```

It's eash to match `A` and `B`, by just swaping the last 2 indices.  It's tempting to just swap the 1st and 3rd for `C`, but that's wrong.  When the 1st is moved to the end, the others shift over without changing their order:

```
In [38]: for la in range(na):
    ...:     for lb in range(nb):
    ...:         for lc in range(nc):
    ...:             print(la,lb,lc,'A',A[la,lb,lc],'B',B[la,lc,lb],'C',C[lb,lc,la])

0 0 0 A 1 B 1 C 1
0 0 1 A 2 B 2 C 2
0 1 0 A 3 B 3 C 3
0 1 1 A 4 B 4 C 4
1 0 0 A 5 B 5 C 5
1 0 1 A 6 B 6 C 6
1 1 0 A 7 B 7 C 7
1 1 1 A 8 B 8 C 8
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems `A[la, lb, lc] = B[la, lc, lb] = C[lb, lc, la]` is the result of transpose. I thought about the opposite, `A[la, lc, lb] = B[la, lb, lc]` and `A[lb, lc, la] = C[la, lb, lc]`, that is not true in general.

Comment: With 2d, it doesn't match which way you think it, the 2 dimensions are switched.  But with 3d, it's harder to keep the dimensions straight.  Sometimes it helps to start with an array like `np.zeros((2,3,4))` and look at the resulting shapes. With (1,2,0) I focus on where I'm moving the first dimension of `A` - to the end.